# Access Text From CSS Textbox

Tags: c#, html, css

I am using the below html & css to create and align textboxes.  It does the job perfectly, but anytime I Try to access the text from my C# code behind by using `txtfield1.Text` I get a compile error of txtfield1 does not exist in the current context. 
**This is my css**

```
.left
{
  padding:2px;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}

.right 
{
  padding:2px;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float:left;
}

.text1 
{
  width: 70px;
}

.text2 
{
  width: 150px;
}
```

**and this is my html markup**

```
<div>
  <div class="left">Option One:</div>
  <div class="right"><input class="txtfield1" type="text" runat="server"/></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="left">Option Two:</div>
  <div class="right"><input class="text2" type="text" runat="server"/></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="left">Option Three:</div>
  <div class="right"><input class="text2" type="text" runat="server"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using `txtField1.Text`.and your markup is `<input class="txtfield1"`

Comment: @Developer - I have tried both ways and C# is not seeing the field.  Ill update post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your html carefully.

```
 <div class="right"><input class="txtfield1" id="txtfieldid1" type="text" runat="server"/></div>
```

**You need to assign an id then you can access the variable at c# code behind**

```
txtfieldid1.text
```

You are not using `txtfield1`.That's why you get compile error.

Comment: I am using input class, what would I do to be able to access the field in my C# code behind?